# How to parse an Object result from mongoHQ with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose

Hey I am new to nodejs and mongoose and am trying to make a simple login and register form with my mongoHQ Database. I have register saving the data, and I am able to pull the data from the DB to print the object to the console, but how do I parse the object result for the username and password locations

```
        // Define schema
        var UserSchema = new Schema({ 
            password: {type: String, required: true },
            username: {type: String, required: true }
        });
        var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
             User.password = req.body.password;
             User.username = req.body.username; 
        console.log("going to find users");
        User.findOne({username: User.username, password: User.password}, function(err, docs){
            console.log(docs.username);
        });
```

At this point I want to do something like docs.username or docs[0], can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: You must not assign your `req.body.password, req.body.username` to the User model e.g. remove this : `User.password = req.body.password; User.username = req.body.username`, use `User.findOne({username: req.body.username, password : req.body.password }, func....` and you will have docs populated with the document of the user, so you could access `docs.username; docs.password`

Comment: Although I recommend you to use something else for authentication ( since you are a beginner in using node ) - for example https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport